# freeradius request proxy to freediameter

Tags: freeradius, diameter-protocol, free-diameter

I am looking to proxy EAP-SIM request from freeRADIUS to freeDiameter, the process involves:

1. Set proxy on freeRADIUS (my status is requested is not being proxied)
2. Set NAS on freeDiameter (due to lack of documentation I am not able to understand where to define Radius as a NAS)
3. Send message back to freeRADIUS (I think this will be done automatically by Diameter once the above tasks are completed)

my current status is freeRADIUS is:

```
[suffix] Looking up realm "wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org" for ser-Name = "1404100508859867@wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org"
[suffix] Found realm "wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org"
[suffix] Adding Stripped-User-Name = "1404100508859867"
[suffix] Adding Realm = "wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org"
[suffix] Proxying request from user 1404100508859867 to realm wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org
[suffix] Preparing to proxy authentication request to realm "wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org" 
++[suffix] = updated
[eap] Request is supposed to be proxied to Realm wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org.  Not doing EAP.
++[eap] = noop
```

in the end, I get an error message which says:

```
+} # group authorize = updated
ERROR: Failed to find live home server for realm wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org
There was no response configured: rejecting request 6
Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
# Executing group from file /etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+group REJECT {
[attr_filter.access_reject]     expand: %{User-Name} -> 1404100508859867@wlan.mnc010.mcc404.3gppnetwork.org
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
++[attr_filter.access_reject] = updated
+} # group REJECT = updated
```

I am not able to understand what I might be doing wrong

Also, a point to note I don't get any debug in my Diameter:

```
freeDiameterd
libfdproto initialized.
libgnutls '2.12.23', libgcrypt '1.4.5', initialized.
Generating fresh Diffie-Hellman parameters of size 1024 (this takes some time)... 
All extensions loaded.
-- Configuration :
  Debug trace level ...... : +1
  Configuration file ..... : /usr/etc/freeDiameter/freeDiameter.conf
  Diameter Identity ...... : diameter.<identity hidden> (l:19)
  Diameter Realm ......... : <identity hidden> (l:10)
  Tc Timer ............... : 30
  Tw Timer ............... : 30
  Local port ............. : 3868
  Local secure port ...... : 3869
  Number of SCTP streams . : 30
  Number of server threads : 4
  Local endpoints ........ : 
                             [103.206.180.2]:0 {C---}
  Local applications ..... : (none)
  Flags : - IP ........... : Enabled
          - IPv6 ......... : DISABLED
          - Relay app .... : DISABLED
          - TCP .......... : Enabled
          - SCTP ......... : DISABLED
          - Pref. proto .. : SCTP
          - TLS method ... : Separate port
  TLS :   - Certificate .. : /etc/ssl/certs/freeDiameter.pem
          - Private key .. : /etc/ssl/private/freeDiameter.key
          - CA (trust) ... : /etc/ssl/certs/freeDiameter.pem (1 certs)
          - CRL .......... : (none)
          - Priority ..... : (default: 'NORMAL')
          - DH bits ...... : 1024
  Origin-State-Id ........ : 1493381358
freeDiameterd daemon initialized.
```

All the help in this will be highly appreciable.

Comment: You haven't configured a RADIUS client in FreeDiameter, your shared secrets are wrong, or your IP addresses don't match what you've configured.  Those would be the first few obvious things to check.

Comment: hello Arran, 
Thanks for your response, 
do you have idea how to load RADIUS client in freeDiameter ?

Comment: Nope, else i'd have posted that as an answer.  You're going to need to do some research :)

Comment: Thanks, Arran, already doing this and part of that fact-finding is StackOverflow query ;) FYI, I found something as app_radgw but getting error in loading the module see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43730089/error-while-loading-app-radgw-in-freediameter?noredirect=1#comment74504125_43730089